# How to get item's height after is has been created?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8

I want to fill a `ListView` with items as long as they fit on the current page sothat I do not have to scroll. For this I want to add an item, check it's height and if it is too big to fit in the remaining space I want to remove it.

My questions are:

1. Is there a smarter way to solve this?
2. When to check the realized items height?

In Windows 8.1 the `ListView` control does not have an `ItemRealized` or `ItemCreated` event. So when to check the item's container size?

I try to get the size via

```
UIElement container = (UIElement)ItemsListView.ContainerFromItem(obj);
double height = container.DesiredSize.Height;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the intention that you want to basically want a paginated collection (e.g. 100 items, show 10 items per page @ 10 pages), or do you explicitly just want one ListView?

Comment: You are right, the intention is to implement paging. But my items can have different heights sothat it might happen that on the first page there are 3 items, on the second 5 items and so on...

Comment: With different sizes, you'll probably need to manage your own active list/page in the View's code behind. The ActualHeight property will be useful for determining availalble container size and size of the items I would think.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a built-in solution for paginated collections, besides the [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), which is probably not what you want.

Pagination usually is something that should be done on the ViewModel/business side of things, so if you know the sizes of the objects ahead of time, you may be able to do something like this [How to paginate an ObservableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329988/how-to-paginate-an-observablecollection) or [MVVM paging & sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305883/mvvm-paging-sorting/5306328#5306328), providing the view with the correct number of items.

If it needs to be more dynamic and flexible, this is a pretty good article about pagination using a `WrapPanel` as the ItemsPanel for an `ItemsControl` http://imduff.blogspot.com/2008/02/this-is-way-how-i-implemented-paging.html.