# Opposite of Skip method in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, skip

I'm currently using the `ObservableCollection` method `Skip` to display the next `n` items in my list when a user presses the `Next` `Button`.

Is there a method or a simple to way to do the opposite? That is go backwards in the list?

This is what I'm using at the moment.

```
myObservableCollectionObject.Skip(5).Take(5);
```

So this would display items `6 - 10` if I had just seen `1 - 5`. When another `Button` is pressed, I would like to display the previous 5 items `(1 - 5)`.

Comment: `col.Skip(pagesize * page).Take(pagesize)`

Answer (score 2):

You can keep an index, changed by the Forward/Backward button, increasing/decreasing the index by 5.

Than use that index in Skip(index) to skip the requested items.

```
int _index = 0;

void OnForwardButton(...)
{
   _index += 5;
}

void OnBackwardButton(...)
{
   _index -= 5;
}
```

Than use in your statement:

```
myObservableCollectionObject.Skip(_index).Take(5);
```

I didn't add safety statements to check the index and to make 5 into a constant.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternatives:

- [How to paginate an ObservableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329988/how-to-paginate-an-observablecollection) ([Paginated ObservableCollection @ CodePlex](https://paginatedcollection.codeplex.com/)).
- [Paged Collection View in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003845/paged-collection-view-in-wpf).

### Custom ("manual") implementation:

It seems the "original" collection must be stored and "go to previous/next" commands should be implemented as calculating "filtered" collection since there is no way to rewind the "filtered" collection (it does not have previous items).

Use the "filtered" collection to display.

Answer (score 0):

Im ny case I've prepared few simple extension methods for my self to protect "page" out of range:

```
public static int EnsurePageNo(
                        this int page, 
                        int pageSize, 
                        int totalItems)
{
    if (pageSize < 1) 
         throw new ArgumentException("Page size should at least 1.", "pageSize");
    if (page < 1) return 1;

    return page > totalItems / pageSize 
                ? totalItems / pageSize + 1;
                : page;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Page<T>(
                this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                int page, 
                int pageSize)
{
    var toSkip = pageSize * page;
    var take = pageSize;

    return source.Skip(toSkip).Take(take);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> SafePage<T>(
                  this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                  int page, 
                  int? pageSize, 
                  int totalItems)
{
    // no paging
    if (!pageSize.HasValue) return source;

    if (page < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Page number should be greater or equal 1.");

    var pgSize = pageSize.Value;
    page = page.EnsurePageNo(pgSize, totalItems);
    return source.Page(page - 1, pgSize);
}
```

Usage:

```
var totalCount = myObservableCollectionObject.Count();
var result = myObservableCollectionObject.SafePage(page, pageSize, totalCount);
```

Maybe it is too much for simple  paging, but it is reusable and I don't need to remember math expressions.